# MultipleCompilationErrorsException in Jenkins pipeline because of a character escaping issue, can you find the issue?

Tags: bash, escaping, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm writing a Jenkins pipeline which builds a docker host on AWS ECS.

In build.gradle I have the following lines:

```
imageSettings['Worker'] = [dockerImageName: 'ubi-celery-worker',   dockerImageTag: 'latest', inputDir: dockerWorkerOutputDir]
imageSettings['Flower'] = [dockerImageName: 'ubi-celery-flower',   dockerImageTag: 'latest', inputDir: dockerFlowerOutputDir]
imageSettings['Online'] = [dockerImageName: 'ubi-online-services', dockerImageTag: 'latest', inputDir: dockerOnlineOutputDir]
```

The job is configured with a default environment parameter which is dev, and then these three lines are correct.

My task is to make this job able to deploy to all environments.

Before the gradle task begins running, and incase the environment name is not "dev", I need to change these 3 lines to add a prefix to the dockerImageName.

Example:

This value: "ubi-celery-worker" needs to be changed to: "product-env-ubi-celery-worker"

Here's the relevant portion of code in the pipeline where I change the lines:

```
sh("""
    sed -i "s|awsAccountId.*|awsAccountId=\$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID|g" gradle.properties
    sed -i "s|awsRegion.*|awsRegion=\$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION|g" gradle.properties
    for line in \$(grep "\[dockerImageName" ubi-py-server/build.gradle | awk '{print \$4}'| tr -d "\'\|,"); do imgname="product-${ENV}-${line}" ; echo \$imgname ; sed -i "s|dockerImageName: '\$line|dockerImageName: '\$imgname|g" ubi-py-server/build.gradle ;done
""")
```

I'm talking about the third line in the sh clouse.

$line is the "for loop" iterator.

$ENV is a groovy parameter.

If I run it in a terminal on the Jenkins server, it edits the lines properly and add the required prefix.

But if I run it through the Jenkins job, I get the following error:

```
Started by user itai ganot

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 74: unexpected char: '\' @ line 74, column 32.
                                        for line in \$(grep "\[dockerImageName" ubi-py-server/build.gradle | awk '{print \$4}'| tr -d "\'\|,"); do imgname="atime-${ENV}-${line}" ; echo \$imgname ; sed -i "s|dockerImageName: '\$line|dockerImageName: '\$imgname|g" ubi-py-server/build.gradle ;done
                                  ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
```

Stuff I tried:

- Escaping some suspicious "$" signs, changing double quotes to single quotes... nothing helps and I keep getting this error.

Can you find where do I lack the correct escaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the character escaping myself, here's the fixed line:

```
for line in \$(grep "\\[dockerImageName" ubi-py-server/build.gradle | awk '{print \$4}'| tr -d "\'\\|,"); do imgname="product-$ENV-\$line" ; echo \$imgname ; sed -i "s|dockerImageName: '\$line|dockerImageName: '\$imgname|g" ubi-py-server/build.gradle ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

(Don't have the rep to post this as a comment.)
I have found it helpful to break long complicated strings like this into smaller portions and then use string concatenation to combine them into a string to pass to the sh (or bat) step.